# Django: Two types of users logged in at same time

Tags: python, django, session-cookies, django-settings, django-sessions

I have two applications in Django (one for admin and one for regular users). I want to allow the admin user to login in admin panel and also login in the home page as a regular user (two different users with different credentials).

I know that the session is saved as a cookie, so my best guess is that I have to use a different SESSION_COOKIE_NAME in each app, but I don't know if this is the best approach.

How can I set different login sessions for each app?.

Comment: I fail to see how that is useful or how it can be necessary since you can always use two browsers for testing. Anyway I seriously doubt it can be done within the Django auth system, I haven't found any library that enables you to do that and i think it will require a lot of coding and time to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way (assumed on Unix based OS):

1. first create new value in /etc/hosts:
     127.0.0.1 {your local testdomain}
2. add {your local testdomain} to ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py
3. Open your application e.g. on {your local testdomain}:8000
4. Open admin interface on localhost:8000/admin

Because of the cookie policy the session data is stored per domain.